# Importing JSON file into DynamoDB

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-transcribe

I am new to AWS, DynamoDB, and Python so I am struggling with accomplishing this task. I am using Amazon Transcribe with video and getting output in a JSON file. I then wish to store this data in DynamoDB.

Currently I am using a Lambda function to automate the process when the JSON file is dumped into an S3 bucket. Whenever the process occurs, I get an error in CloudWatch:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key type in the item
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 79, in lambda_handler
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict) # Adds string of JSON file into the database
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 623, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Here is my Python code that is attempting to create a DynamoDB table and then parse the JSON file:

```
import boto3  # import to pull AWS SDK for Python
import json  # import API for Python to work with JSON files
import time  # import time fucntions
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')  # creates low-level service client to AWS S3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')  # creates resource client to AWS DynamoDB


# When a .JSON file is added into the linked S3 bucket, another JSON file is created which contains
# the information about the S3 Bucket and the name of the file that was added to the bucket

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(str(event))

    # Print the JSON file created by S3 into CloudWatch Logs when an item is added into the bucket

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

    # Here the name of the S3 bucket is assigned to the variable 'bucket'
    # by grabbing the name from the JSON file created

    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    # Here the name of the file itself is assigned to the varibale 'json_file_name'
    # again by grabbing the name of the added file from the JSON file

    tname = json_file_name[:-5]

    # Defines the name of the table being added to dynamodb by using the name of S3 JSON file
    # *Use of [:.5] will strip the last five characters off the end of the file name

    print(tname)

    # Prints the name of the table into CloudWatch Logs

    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)

    # The json_object variable is assigned the values of the 'bucket' and the 'json_file_name'
    # This uses the boto3 client service and the rest of the script will reference the specified
    # S3 bucket and the JSON file that was added to the bucket

    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()

    # The jsonFileReader variable takes this object and read the body of JSON file

    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)

    # Using the json.loads function, the arrays of the JSON file are converted into a string

    table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName=tname, ## Define table name from name of JSON file in S3
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'type', #Primary Key
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition Key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'type',
            'AttributeType': 'S' #AttributeType N meas 'Number'
        }

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput=
        {
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 10000,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 10000
        }
    )

#    table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName=tname)
    print(str(jsonDict))


    table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName=tname)

    table = dynamodb.Table(tname)  # Specifies table to be used

    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)  # Adds string of JSON file into the database
```

I'm not very familiar with parsing nested JSON files and have no experience with DynamoDB. Any assistance to get this functioning would be extremely helpful!

Here is the JSON file I am trying to parse:

```
{
    "results": {
        "items": [{
            "start_time": "15.6",
            "end_time": "15.95",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.6502",
                "content": "Please"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": null,
                "content": "."
            }],
            "type": "punctuation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "15.95",
            "end_time": "16.2",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.9987",
                "content": "And"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "16.21",
            "end_time": "16.81",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.9555",
                "content": "bottles"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "16.81",
            "end_time": "17.01",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.7179",
                "content": "of"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "17.27",
            "end_time": "17.36",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.6274",
                "content": "rum"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "18.12",
            "end_time": "18.5",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.9977",
                "content": "with"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "18.5",
            "end_time": "19.1",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.3689",
                "content": "tattoos"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "19.11",
            "end_time": "19.59",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "1.0000",
                "content": "like"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "19.59",
            "end_time": "20.22",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.9920",
                "content": "getting"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "20.22",
            "end_time": "20.42",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.5659",
                "content": "and"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "20.43",
            "end_time": "20.97",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.6694",
                "content": "juggle"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "21.2",
            "end_time": "21.95",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "0.8893",
                "content": "lashes"
            }],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }, {
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": null,
                "content": "."
            }],
            "type": "punctuation"
        }, {
            "start_time": "21.95",
            "end_time": "22.19",
            "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": "1.0000",
                "content": "And"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

The other issue I seem to have is how to deal with punctuation since AWS Transcribe does not assign time stamps to these items.

Any assistance is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The important thing in a database is the **key** , this should be unique to your data row. In your case **[Option 1]** if you  intent to put each json file in a separate table name (tname), you will have to provide a set of unique values which in this case seems to be **start_time** . Alternatively  **[Option 2]** you can have the same table with all the current and future data put here and keep the key as tname assummin this would be unique to the data.

**Option 1**

Replace 'AttributeName': 'type' in KeySchema and AttributeDefinitions to
'AttributeName': '**start_time**'

```
##This is a way to batch write
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for item in jsonDict["results"]["items"]:   
        batch.put_item(Item=item)
```

**Option 2**

Here you should not be creating table everytime. Just create it once and then each entry is added to the database. In the code below the table name is "commonTable"

**Replace** 'AttributeName': 'type' in KeySchema and AttributeDefinitions to
**'AttributeName': 'tname'**

```
table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName="commonTable")
table = dynamodb.Table(tname)  # Specifies table to be used
jsonDict['tname'] = tname      # this is also the key name 'tname'
table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)
```